# Unable to format double values in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV data like the below:

```
time_value,annual_salary
5/01/19 01:02:16,120.56
06/01/19 2:02:17,12800
7/01/19 03:02:18,123.00
08/01/19 4:02:19,123isdhad
```

I want to consider only `numeric values` along with **decimal** values. Basically, I want to ignore the last record since it is alphanumeric in the case of `annual_salary` and which I was able to do so. But, when I tried it convert it to the proper decimal values it is giving me incorrect results. Below is my code:

```
df = df.withColumn("annual_salary", regexp_replace(col("annual_salary"), "\.", ""))
df = df.filter(~col("annual_salary").rlike("[^0-9]"))
df.show(truncate=False)
df.withColumn("annual_salary", col("annual_salary").cast("double")).show(truncate=False)
```

But it gives me records like the below:

[image]

which is incorrect.

`Expected output`:

```
annual_salary
120.56
12800.00
123.00
```

What could be wrong here? Should I need to implement UDF for this type of conversion?

Comment: you're removing the period here `regexp_replace(col("annual_salary"), "\.", "")` and then casting to double here `.cast("double")` so naturally a number that started as 120.56 will turn into 12056.0

Comment: Yeah, I know that is wrong. What can be done over here then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try cast Decimal Type.

```
  df.where(~col('annual_salary').rlike('[A-Za-z]')).withColumn('annual_salary', col('annual_salary').cast(DecimalType(38,2))).show()

+----------------+-------------+
|      time_value|annual_salary|
+----------------+-------------+
|5/01/19 01:02:16|       120.56|
|06/01/19 2:02:17|     12800.00|
|7/01/19 03:02:18|       123.00|
+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: If I add a record like `123 USD` and when I try your code it doesn't get filtered out. It shows `null`. Why Is it so?

Comment: See my edits and let me know. I had filtered out small alphas only. Caps now included